# How to upload large text files using REST service

Tags: java, rest, text, bulk

We need to update a couple of remotes tables with information provided by our clients, to our central server.
Currently we're doing it by generating csv files, then uploading them via FTP (secured by VPN) or form upload, then a PHP Script process them and dump them into the database.

We'd like to implement a REST service that would be able to do that.
Is it recommended that I send all the information as JSON instead of the text files?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I've been looking several solutions but none come close to what we need to do.

Comment: What are those solutions which do not fit your needs ? Otherwise we may end up suggesting those again.

Comment: So far I've seen: plain data in json, compressed data in json, compress the txt files and directly upload them. I want it to be as fast & lightweight as possible. We're developing our rest services with java & glassfish.

Comment: Generally speaking (for text but maybe also for binary data), should I be uploading the data converting it to Base64 ? Doesn't it add a lot of size to the data?